# Chrome not using cached files when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, browser-cache

I have a page with some script files embedded. All of these script files are served with appropriate caching headers including cache-control: private, pragma: private, expires: *one month from now*... When I navigate to a page and then select the address in the address bar and navigate to it again, the cache works fine but when I refresh the page, some of the scripts on that page are re-fetched.

When I look at the request, I can see that chrome sends the request header Cache-Control:max-age=0. There are other files on that page which seem to always cache properly (and for which chrome does not send a Cache-Control:max-age=0 request header). Why does chrome force some files to refresh and not others (assuming they all have the same response headers)??